# LTO tape drive: "/dev/st0: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: linux, centos, tape

I can write to the tape drive (tar -cf /dev/st0 file) and retrieve files from the tape
drive (tar xvf /dev/st0 file). But the problem is when I attempt to use the 'mt' command to check the status of the tape drive,
**command.**

```
mt -f /dev/st status
```

the following error is shown

```
/dev/st0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

The tape drive is being recognized by the server since I can retrieve and write to the tape drive. How can I get the status of the tape drive using the `mt` command or any other
command?

Comment: What hardware is this exactly?

Comment: I am using HP LTO3 for taking backup...!!!!!

Comment: The simple answer is that every device driver implements some subset of the basic operations/functions (open, close, read, write, seek, ioctl, etc…) for that device – and you got a tape driver that implements read and write, but not ioctl.